# Why is the correlation function of local operators in topological field theory independent of the position they are inserted?

Tags: topological-field-theory

I am reading "A mini course on topological strings"(hep-th/0504147).

In the last paragraph of section 3.1, author mentioned that if a topological field theory have general coordinate invariance, then the correlation function would be independent of the position where the operator are inserted.

The proof scratches as follows. By doing an arbitrary general coordinate transformation, we change both the coordinates on M and its metric, under which the correlation functions should be invariant. Then, using the topological invariance, we can transform back the metric to its old value. The combined effect is that we have only changed the position of operators.

The proof depends greatly on the general coordinate invariance of correlation function. However, the author mentioned another fact that the correlation function of a topological field theory would be dependent on the complex structure of the manifold (where the theory live on).

However, general coordinate invariance in physicist's language is indeed diffeomorphism invariance, which would *not* preserve complex structure of the manifold in general. As the result, *it is biholomorphic map rather than the diffeomorphic map that would keep the correlation function invariant.*

However, if it is the case, then the correlation function would depend on the position where the operator are inserted. An example is the 4 point correlation function on a sphere.

As the result, there must be some contradictions in the fact that "correlation function does not depend on the position it inserted" and the fact that "correlation function in general would depend on the complex structure". If you have some insight on it, please tell me.